# trying to load the div only when list item is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I am trying to use a [tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/03/16/expanding-image-menu/) that is essentially suppose to be expanding images to show content.

I am however changing how I am using the tutorial, to represent bottles and want it to open the content and make it responsive unlike the tutorial. 
I have tried to play with all the numbers and possibilities, but I cant seem to find a right solution for dynamically loading the content descriptions only when the bottle is clicked.

I was playing with

```
.onclick function
```

but it did not work, mainly because I am constructing it right as per my limited skill of javascript and jquery.

Essentially the tutorial uses pixels and relies on the fact that position of the preview images hides the content until it is clicked, however in my case the position is calculated by % and therefore will be the same and is visible during and after clicking it.

Also my difficulty lies in targeting only the description of the li preview that is clicked.

I am really not someone who can construct a missing part of jquery code, therefore I am at a loss of solutions..

here is the
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5fn6w0b/)

I was asked if I could do a mockup of what I want to achieve
[image]
here it is

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you want to happen. Can you maybe mock a picture of what you want the end result to be?

Comment: Hi sure I have attached the mock

Comment: That plugin - as good as it seems looks a little too advanced for what you need? All you need is on('click') to control things not a sliding animating plugin.

Comment: True as I think about it. But its the sliding animation that I like. The fact that this plugin does not allow for a responsiveness is the down side. [http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/03/16/expanding-image-menu/] this what the plugin does

Comment: I am not quite sure how I would achieve the slide effect and have the content appear just using onclick?